# How to create an Html file from the page to feed into a translator in AEM6?

Tags: aem

I am working in a project where the pages are being created in English and Spanish languages. A translator is being used to translate the English pages to the Spanish ones. However, I don't need to integrate the translator into AEM.

What I need is to create a file from the English pages that can be feed to the translator. After translating the file, it will be uploaded to AEM and will have to figure out a way to use that file to update the Spanish pages.

The translator can take files in many different formats like word, html, xml etc.

Has anyone been in the same situation? What all are my options to achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the translator engine you are going to use? I feel having a translator integrated to AEM will reduce your work of downloading the content pages and feeding to translator and uploading back to AEM. and your question can't be answered as there will be multiple solutions to achieve it.

Comment: @VAr Thanks for your reply. We are going to use Trados translator.. Can you please provide one of the solutions to achieve it?

Comment: If you are using human translation I would suggest to have a look on smartling translation plugin(I had an experience with it on hybris and AEM and it was quite good). It can grab your content into translation system, translate it (even by your translators if you want) and upload back to new localisation structure.

Answer (score 0):

One solution i can suggest as your translator tool is going to accept the **html** files as input. you can get the pages easily from the AEM just by replacing your AEM page `.html` extension with `export.zip` in the URL and requesting the page will download the whole page as static html along with **images**, **.js** and **.css** files.

**Example:** If your page is `http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/contacts.html` then the download page request will be `http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/contacts.export.zip` which will download the page to your local along with CSS as shown below screenshot. (downloaded Contact.zip extracted folder containing AEM page which has been opened in browser.)
[image: page download]

Again solution has to be designed which content you want to push for the translator which can be worked out by programmatically by using [PageExporter API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ref/javadoc/index.html?com/day/cq/wcm/contentsync/PageExporter.html) and more information you can find at the [Adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/content/page-exporter.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you need to download and then upload translated version I would suggest [Package Manager](http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp) as it can provide page content in xml format and then install it back.

1) You can create package from target page(site).

2) Download zip archive

3) Unarchive it to file structure with xml's

4) Translate those xml files

5) In the file structure from step (3) you can rename `en` folder to `es`

6) change configuration in the `META-INF/vault/filter.xml` from `en` node path to `es`

7) replace translated file

8) create normal zip archive and install with [Package Manager](http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp) back to AEM.